# How to store the item popped off from Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a program where i have to incorporate the use of vectors. But the problem is that i need to store the value of the popped off item from the vector. The vector's `popback()` doesn't really help with saving as it takes no arguments and has void return type. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: there's `front` and `back`. in general, it's often a good idea to check out some documentation.

Comment: What if the case if that we want to pop off a specific item ( not front or back ) and pop that off and store it temporarily. We can definitely erase the item from the vector but what about keeping its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

while ( !v.empty() )
{
   int x = v.back();
   v.pop_back();
   std::cout << x << ' ';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

There are several ways to access elements of a vector as for example back(), front(), operator [], at(), *it where it is an iterator.